# ngOptions syntax for displaying key and value in option tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-chosen

I have an array of country objects and trying to display a dropdown using [Angular chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen)

Angular chosen does not support ng-repeat for the options tag, instead it only supports ngOptions.

My ngOptions syntax is as follows

```
<select chosen class="form-control input-lg" name="countryDropdown" id="countryDropdown"
ng-options="option.name+option.d_code for option in loginCtrl.countryData track by option.code"
ng-model="loginCtrl.selectedOption">

 </select>
```

I want to display both the country name and code i.e India IN but it displays without a space between them i.e. INDIA+91,

How do I add a space between the name and the code?

Sample country object:

```
{
   name: India,
   d_code: +91,
   code: IN

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the space in the string

```
ng-options="option.name+' '+option.d_code for option in loginCtrl.countryData track by option.code"
```